# Resuming Toshiba Qosmio F60 after sleep turns the power off

Tags: sleep, shutdown

The problem is consistent. 
Using Windows 7, without running any service (), just the Basic Windows 7 startup
putting the laptop into sleep works fine but when I try to resume by clicking on any button or the power button, the power goes down suddenly and all lights go off.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your bios, chipset, and graphics drivers.